# Chrome: eventHandler('click', function) doesnt work for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im writing an extension for google chrome.

I have an options.html that contains this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Options Menu</title>
    <script src="chromeoptions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="options">
    <div id="form">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test">
        <div id ="testEvents" style="display:'none'">
            blabla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Chromeoptions.js has this in it:

```
function clicked(string) {
    console.log('clicked');
    if (document.getElementById(string).checked == true) {
        document.getElementById(string + 'Events').style.display = '';
    }
    else document.getElementById(string + 'Events').style.display = 'none';

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', clicked('test'));
});
```

What happens is: on the first load the 'click' eventhandler fires, causing the div 'testEvents' to disappear. Afterwards, nothing happens when I toggle the checkbox. The eventhandler doesnt fire. It doesnt matter if I use 'click' or 'onchange'.

I also tried moving the scripttag to the bottom of the html and putting the 'click' eventhandlers outside the 'DOMContentLoaded' eventHandler, but that also didnt change anything.

So how do I get the eventhandler to fire when I toggle the checkbox?

Comment: Try adding event listener this way: `.addEventListener('click', function(event) { clicked('test') } );`; @Barmar was 10 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `addEventListener` must be a function. You're calling `clicked()` immediately, not passing a function that calls it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {clicked('test')});
});
```

Comment: Jup that works, thanks. but why is it that in my original example, the `addEventListener('click'...` fired right after the document loaded? If I change it the way you suggest it doesnt happen.

Comment: When you put a function call in the arguments of a function, it means to call that function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
<div id ="testEvents" style="display:'none'">
```

maybe try:

```
<div id ="testEvents" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you wanted it to use jquery:

add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and use:

```
$.fn.toggleDiv = function () {

        $(this).each(function () {

            var target = $(this);

            $(target).on('click', function () {
                $('#' + $(target).attr('id') + 'Events').toggle($(target).is(':checked'));
            });
        });
    };

$('input[type=checkbox]').toggleDiv();
```

Which works with multiple events checkboxes:

```
<div id="options">
    <div id="form">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test">
        <div id ="testEvents" style="display:none">
            blabla1
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="test2">
        <div id ="test2Events" style="display:none">
            blabla2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```